# Docker-compose, pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: macos, python-2.7, docker-compose

I am kind of new with docker-compose. Terminal displays this message when building container. Not sure where the problem is.

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-de-Carlos-Arau:webscrap carlosarau$ docker-compose up
Building web
Step 1/5 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> 68e7be49c28c
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be06bd573b0f
Step 3/5 : ADD requirements.txt /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eb33847b4acb
Step 4/5 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e16754e4db86
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),))

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here you can find my Dockerfile and docker-compose yml

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /usr/src/app
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Running on Mac OS Yosemite with python 2.7 (unable to upgrade to 3.6)

Thanks for you help

Comment: Unrelated, but you may know that Python 2.7 is unsupported. If possible, you should use Python 3 .

Answer (score 2):

I see that you use python2.7.

It is unsupported since january 2020. It is possible your problem comes from here.

Your build environment does not recognize the SSL certificate of https://files.pythonhosted.org as valid.

If the root certificate of `files.pythonhosted.org` was added in a more recent python version, that may explain it.

I strongly advise to find a way to update your python to python3 before anything else.

Comment: Yes, although the days before I was able to run the docker-compose up with no problems. No idea why could this happens right now, no changes were made to the docker-compose.yml

Comment: It is most possible that it was a change on `pythonhosted.org` side. If they renewed their certificate based on a new root certificate, the problem occurs if that root certificate was not present in your local python environment but available in a more recent python version.

Comment: If your problem arised on july the 13th at 19:46 GMT+1, it can be that. They renewed their certificate at that date. Or maybe https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7663 Just shooting in the dark here.